# Neural Network With One Hidden Layer Cannot Be Trained

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, mnist

I was trying to implement an NN with one hidden layer by using TensorFlow to recognize MNIST handwritten digits. I was using gradient descent method to train the NN. However, it seems that my training toward the NN did not work at all, as the testing accuracy did not change at all during the training process.

Can anyone help me figure out what went wrong?

Here is my code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)

batch_size = 100

n_batch = mnist.train.num_examples // batch_size

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

#First layer of the NN
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
out1 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1)

#Second layer of the NN
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,10]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(out1, W2) + b2)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - prediction))

train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(prediction, 1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(101):
        for batch in range(n_batch):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y:batch_ys})

        acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x:mnist.test.images, y:mnist.test.labels})
        print("Iter " + str(epoch) + ", Testing Accuracy " + str(acc))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not initialize your model with all zeros.** If you do so, it is likely that the gradient at that point (in the parameter space) is also zero. This results in the gradient update to be non existent, thus your parameters will simply not change. To avoid that **use random initialization**.

i.e.

Change

```
#First layer of the NN
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
out1 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1)

#Second layer of the NN
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,10]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
```

to

```
#First layer of the NN
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([784,10], stddev=0.1))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10], stddev=0.1))
out1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1)
# out1 = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1)

#Second layer of the NN
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10,10], stddev=0.1))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([10],stddev=0.1))
```

Now the model is able to train. You'll also see that I removed the softmax non linearity from the first layer and substituted it with a sigmoid. I did that because softmax layers impose restrictions to the output: it forces that layer's output to add up to one (that's one reason it's often used in the very last layer: to achieve probability interpretation of the final output) . This restriction caused the model to stop learning at 30% accuracy in a quick test. By using a sigmoid the accuracy reached 89%, a much better performance.

Other examples of non linearities you could have used in intermediate layers could be:

- Hyperbolic tangent
- ReLU

Comment: I changed my activation functions in the hidden layers to Relu, the same thing occurs again, the NN cannot be trained, the correctness rate remains unchanged during the training process. Numbers of neurons on each layer are 784-20-10-10. The two hidden layers in NN are using ReLU as the activation function, while the last layer is using softmax. And original values of weights and bias are generated by normal function.

Comment: Got the problem fixed, it seems that my learning rate was too large that caused the ReLU neuron died.

Comment: The actual problem for the model not to train was that zero initialization. Just tried it again and changing initialization to truncated normal works just fine. The second part of the answer was just a side note to show that performance could be enhanced if the softmax function in the first layer was substituted by a either a ReLU, atan or sigmoid.